# Configurable Product - Select Size with Button

Tags: product, configurable-product

I have this design below for my product page;

[image]

I have also setup a Configurable Product for the pillows and have everything working, however I would like to be able to select the sizes using a button, rather than a dropdown (circled in red, in image above).

Is there a way to do so, or any ideas?
I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's posible for example by using jQuery.

```
Array.prototype.inArray = function (value){
  var i;
  for (i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
  if (this[i] === value) {
    return true;
  }
  }return false;
};

function set_size(el,element){
  jQuery(".size").removeClass('selected');
  jQuery(element).addClass('selected');
  jQuery("#attribute491").removeAttr('disabled').append('<option value="'+el+'" selected="">Select...</option>');
  jQuery("#attribute491 :selected").attr('value',el);
}

function make_size(sizes,element){
  jQuery(element).empty();
  var i;
  //console.log(sizes);
  for(i=0;i<sizes.length;i++){
    jQuery(element).append('<div class="size '+sizes[i].label+'" onclick="set_size('+sizes[i].id+',this)" >'+sizes[i].label+'</div>');
  }
}
```

Comment: So I would keep the dropdown, and hide it then? And then add the 3 buttons with the class of size?

Sorry I've never used much js so I'm trying to understand it all :)

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use configurable swatch that is available in magento 1.9 and later. 
I'm using this default system and it is so pretty solution.
Here is the link how could you configurable swatch...
http://www.venustheme.com/configurable-swatches-guide-for-magento-1-9-1/

Comment: If I do this method, is there a way to get the description text to change too? Each size has a different description

Comment: No, there is no way to change the product description with respective size